# EF SaveChangesAsync extremely slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table in which I want to update 100 rows at a time. I have a list of the 100 IDs that I use to find the specific rows. Once found, I update a single column (SyncOk) for each row.

The problem is that updating 100 rows takes around **23 to 30 seconds**.

```
dbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
var count = ids.Count;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var id = ids[i];
    var record = await dbContext.History
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == id);
    record.SyncOk = syncOk;
}
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Some notes:

- `ids` is an `IList<long>` that holds all IDs of interest.
- `syncOk` is a bool.
- I've tried to set the `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` property to false, and then updating the record manually just after setting the `SyncOk` value - doesn't speed things up.

Why is `SaveChangesAsync()` so slow - *how can I increase the speed of the above functionality?* I'm afraid that the table is locked during the 23-30 seconds and will make other services (that use the same table) unable to update it as well.

Comment: It isn't. Something is wrong with the database schema (missing index perhaps?) or a lot of other clients are hitting the same table (still, even 1 sec would be to much). Are there any triggers defined on the talbe? Are you timing `SaveChanges`itself or the entire code which actually executes 100 selects?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: the timing is the duration of executing the entire above code. No other clients are using the table atm. Let me get back to you regarding the index.

Comment: Then you are timing the 100 separate FirstOrDefaultAsync statements that correspond to individual `SELECT TOP 1` queries, **not** SaveChanges. That's simply bad SQL. You should tell EF to load all History items whose ID is in a list, similar to a `WHERE x IN (...)` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried implementing the changes suggested by the two other answers - but with the same performance result (i.e., no change in speed).

I increased the performance greatly (and fixed my issue) by using a raw SQL command:

```
var stringOfIds = string.Join(",", ids);
await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
    $"UPDATE dbo.History SET SyncOk = 1 WHERE Id IN ({stringOfIds})");
```

Answer (score 5):

You are executing a total of `ids.Count` SELECT statements to the database. This can be seen if you add the code:

```
dbContext.Database.Log += Console.WriteLine;
```

Try to minimize the access to the SQL-Instance by fetching all the data at once:

```
var records = await dbContext.History.Where(i => ids.Contains(i.Id)).ToListAsync();
```

Then you should perform the modification you need:

```
foreach(var record in records)
{
    record.SyncOk = syncOk;
}
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

you could also use the `ForEachAsync` which will query the result like the above portion of code also only once:

```
await dbContext.History.Where(i => ids.Contains(i.Id))
                       .ForEachAsync(i => i.SyncOk = syncOk);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO `Select * from History where Id in (YourList)` is performed below.

```
var listOfRecordsToBeUpdated = await dbContext.History
        .Where(r => ids.Contains(r.Id)).ToListAsync();

//It will detect the changes each time when you update the entity
// Make sure you re-enable this after your bulk operation
DataContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

//Iterate through the records and assign your value
listOfRecordsToBeUpdated.Foreach(x=>x.SyncOk = syncOk);

DataContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

await conn.SaveChangesAsync();
```

[Increase performance by disabling AutoDetectChangesEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj556205.aspx)